# Docker Container No route to host error

Tags: docker, networking, iptables, docker-machine

I have the following docker:

```
docker --version
Docker version 17.12.0-ce, build c97c6d6
```

And when I do a CURL to an external URL, it fails:

inside-container$> **curl -u username -p https://countries.c1.com/countries/v1/countries**

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.10.20.30 port 443: No route to host
```

inside-container$> ping countries.c1.com

```
PING countries.c1.com (10.10.20.30): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.10.20.30: icmp_seq=0 ttl=250 time=2.919 ms
--- countries.c1.com ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 2.919/2.919/2.919/0.000 ms
```

So host can be resolved but can't do a curl. When I run the same curl statement from outside of the docker container (e.g docker host or laptop) it works fine!

Any hint pointing me to the right direction would be very much appreciated!

I am not sure what kind of configuration might be relevant. I will provide anything later on if requested.

Comment: what os are you running from? if your running a stripped down micro os this could be the cause... A Curl is a connection via ssl while a ping is a simple network command. They are WAY diff

Comment: Docker container host = Debian Stretch &&
Docker container = whatever os is default

Comment: docker containers normally are not default, you have to call a os at the start from the FROM: command